# how to get city and country by Google plus api ? If do not use geolocation

Tags: google-plus

I using Google Plus API. In the past i got city and country for user. But now it is not working for me. I do not know why? I can not get this information.

Comment: Have you tried the people api?  https://developers.google.com/people/  I think google locked down some stuff in the google+ api

Comment: developers.google.com/people do not return this information. How get city and Country use social id from Google +.

Answer (score 0):

How to get Location user by Google API?. Plesse example.